# How to avoid using pronoun 'who' more than once in a sentence?

Tags: pronouns

This is my sentence that I'm trying to construct:

> Andy **who** knows Polly's dark secret should not tell her boyfriend,
> Jade, **who** is known has a really bad temper.

I couldn't think of a way to rephrase that sentence, so that I can avoid using **who** twice. People might be bored if they read that sentence. By the way, someone told me that it's boring to read.

Comment: Two points: (1) the expression "who knows Polly's dark secret" is a supplementary (non-defining) relative clause, so it should be set off by punctuation such as commas. (2} the final relative clause should be "who is known to have a really bad temper". I don't think the two occurrences of "who" are a problem.

Comment: What @BillJ said. There are several things "wrong" with the cited text, but repeating ***who*** isn't one of them.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with using *who* twice in one sentence.  It's certainly not something that you should work very hard to avoid.  If all of your sentences are like this, it might be a stylistic problem, but it's not actually grammatically wrong.

Comment: Andy knows Polly's dark secret and should not tell her boyfriend, Jade, who is known has a really bad temper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Andy, who knows Polly's dark secret, should not tell her bad-tempered boyfriend Jade.

> Andy, knowing Polly's dark secret, should not tell her boyfriend Jade, known for his really bad temper.

And probably better:

> Andy knows Polly's dark secret, so he should not tell her boyfriend Jade, who is known for having a really bad temper.